# MSSQL DATABASE CONNECTION WITH PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Please i am trying to connect to an mssql database on a different machine. Below is my code but i just keep getting a blank page.

I dont know what the issue may be. i have installed php and the mssql drivers.

```
<?php

    $uid = "******";
    $pwd = "***\$\$****";
    $DB = "***********";
    $serverName = "192.***.**.***";
    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database"=> $DB, "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{

     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

Comment: check with this while making connection: `"Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you display the connection error using `sqlsrv_errors()`.

Load the PHP drivers in `php.ini` file and restart the server.

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

Please see the following example:

```
<?php
   $serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName

   // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
   // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
   $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName");
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

   if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
   }else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
?>
```

For more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

This is for Server 2019 and PHP 7.4.

Download SQLSRV 5.8.0 Drivers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Have this in your php.ini: (depending on hardware 32 vs 64)

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64
extension=sqlsrv_74_ts_x64
```

Use this to create a mssql connection:

```
Function connect_db() {
            $this->connectionInfo = Array("UID" => DB_USER, "PWD" => DB_PASSWORD, "Database" => DB_NAME);
            $this->conn = SQLSRV_CONNECT(DB_SERVER, $this->connectionInfo);
            if ($this->conn){ return; }
            else {echo "Error";die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));}
        }
```